# Summing up and then subtracting values based on another column

Tags: sql

so basically I have a Database where I have OrderID, CustomerID, OrderValue and Payment. These are the only important columns from the Orders table. What I want to do is basically select a certain customer and see if that person is a good client or a bad one. So I want to SELECT the CustomerID of the different Orders, and make two different sums, one where the Payment='Y' and the other where the Payment='N'. After that I want to subtract the two, and depending if the result is a negative one or a positive one, saying that my client is bad or good.

```
SELECT SUM(OrderValue) FROM Orders
WHERE Payment='Y' and CustomerID=@givenValue

SELECT SUM(OrderValue) FROM Orders
WHERE Payment='N' and CustomerID=@givenValue
```

So now basically I have my two sums. I know there needs to be a larger SELECT that basically encompasses the other two. And in this larger SELECT I need to somehow substract the other two small ones, but I do not know what operation to use because even if I write "minus" or "-" or "as difference", I always get back different errors. I know the "big SELECT" should have

```
SELECT @givenValue
```

and then at some point I need to add an if statement so that if the end value is <0 or >0 I need to

```
print 'This client is a bad one'
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or some shortcuts I can take that maybe don't even require such a long statement? Thanks in advance.

I am also using "@givenValue" because I want to write code in VisualBasic and create a Form in which the user can introduce in a textbox the CustomerID he wants to search for and check if he is a good client or a bad one.

Comment: MySQL or Postgres? Those are two quite different databases

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Payment='Y' THEN OrderValue ELSE 0 END) -  
       SUM(CASE WHEN Payment='N' THEN OrderValue ELSE 0 END) result
FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerID = @givenValue
```

Or use also a `CASE` expression to get the type of client:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN
            SUM(CASE WHEN Payment='Y' THEN OrderValue ELSE 0 END) >  
            SUM(CASE WHEN Payment='N' THEN OrderValue ELSE 0 END) THEN 'good'
            ELSE 'bad'
       END type_of_client
FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerID = @givenValue
```